# How can i duplicate a CSS style?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, css-selectors

On the .master file i have...

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="1"><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="Div1">
    <ul>
       <li class="1"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and on the css file i have

```
#menu {
    width: 940px;
    height: 49px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

So how can use the same style **"#menu"** both for the `<div id="menu">` AND the `<div id="Div1">` ?

Comment: CSS selector names should start with numerical characters, always use proper names like `mydiv`. Numbers can be used like `mydiv1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can target both elements:

```
#menu, #Div1 {
```

but the more clean way is probably to use a class to set the properties:

```
.default_menu {
```

and giving that class to both elements:

```
<div id="menu" class="default_menu">
 ......
<div id="Div1" class="default_menu">
```

classes are independent from a specific element, and usually the better option. Use classes where possible, and IDs only in very, very specific cases of unique elements.

You can also assign multiple classes - as many as you want - to one element:

```
<div id="menu" class="default_menu menu_big">
```

if a property was set in both `default_menu` and `menu_big`, the setting from `menu_big` will override the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of classes like (you may change the name `.menu` to something which makes sense for the two div´s):

```
.menu {
    width: 940px;
    height: 49px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

And:

```
<div class="menu" id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="1"><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="Div1">
    <ul>
        <li class="1"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use a class

```
<div class="menu">...</div>
```

And in your css

```
.menu {...}
```

OR target both divs

```
#menu, #Div1 {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use classes instead of ids for that reusable styles:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="1"><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="Div1" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="1"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.menu {
    width: 940px;
    height: 49px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to, it's just better. You can do what @pekka suggested with comma separated selectors too.

Comment: @hookedonwinter True, but if they use the same attributes they properly share the same class of items.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that you can do as @pekka suggest but I tried to propose what i thought it was the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and target both divs:

```
div#menu, div#Div1 {
    css goes here
}
```